# Transferring layer files from ArcGIS Pro to QGIS

Tags: qgis, layer-file

I have access to ArcGIS Pro at my workplace and will be transferring a project over to someone who will be using QGIS.
I have saved my layers as a layer file but the problem is that the other person is unable to import .lyrx files to QGIS. 
Does anyone know how I can transfer the project to them and include all the symbology settings I have created?